# Added chapter with addcontentsline does not adapt style of ToC

Tags: bibliographies, table-of-contents, chapters

I added my BibTeX references following:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
%\setlength{\bibsep}{3mm} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

but within my ToC the style is not adapted and the page numbering not aligned

The output looks like:

[image: TOC excerpt]

but References should be formated like Conclusion, including the chapter number and page number aligned right. 
How can I adjust the style of the added chapter to be formatted appropriate?

Here's a working example that illustrates it

```
\documentclass
[
a4paper,
english,
twoside,
11pt
]
{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}           
\usepackage{amstext}         
\usepackage{enumerate}        
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{array}            
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}         
\usepackage{parskip}          
\usepackage{xcolor}           
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}     
\usepackage{makeidx}          
\usepackage{multicol}         
\usepackage[numbers, square]{natbib}  
\usepackage{listings}

\makeindex 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % ToC

% add odd sections to illustrate
\section{chapter 1}
\section{chapter 2}
\section{chapter 3}
\subsection{chapter 3.1}
\subsection{chapter 3.2}
\section{chapter 4}

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter{\bibname}}

% add chapter for references
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}


\end{document}
```

The output in ToC is still References1, but the page number should be aligned right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem so other users can reproduce the problem easily and accurately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using `natbib`, which I guess from the style `plainnat`, I recommend redefining `\bibsection` in your preamble, instead of using `\addcontentsline` in the document:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter{\bibname}}
```

Originally `\bibsection` uses `\chapter*` which doesn't create a TOC entry, in contrast to `\chapter`.

If you use a class without chapters, such as `article`, define it using `\section` and possibly `\refname`:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\refname}}
```

With your minimal example, I got:

[image: natbib section example]

Comment: @80leaves The bibliography won't be numbered if it's put after `\backmatter` in the **book** class.

Comment: This makes the bibliography receive an appendix letter if it appears after an `\appendix` command. How can this be avoided?

Comment: @oarfish That's the way `\appendix` works - following chapters get a letter instead of a number. But it depends on the class. Perhaps ask this as a new question.